# Procdump: Increase hang trigger time to more than 5 seconds

Tags: windows, dump, procdump

If I want to create a dump file if my process waits for more than 30 seconds, is there a way to do it through procdump? Currently it has default 5 seconds. But I don't see anywhere to increase that time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option, but it should be possible to fake it with `-h -s 20`. `-h` will wait for 5 seconds and write a dump, `-s 20` will wait for another 20 seconds before it checks the condition again, which will require another 5 seconds. You then get 2 crash dumps and you just ignore the first one.

However, this may give you a lot false positive dumps if your application often lags between 5 and 30 seconds.